# Can we use AWS VPC CNI on Kubernetes cluster in AWS when not using EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am planning to set up a Kubernetes cluster in AWS without using EKS. Since EKS provides **Amazon VPC CNI** for managing networking at pod level, which provides better networking, I am planning to use the same.

I need to know, whether it is possible my Kubernetes cluster with **Amazon VPC CNI**, if yes, can somebody provide me the document or how to perform it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can.
Download manifest - https://github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/blob/master/config/v1.5/aws-k8s-cni.yaml

And run `kubectl apply -f aws-k8s-cni.yaml`

Did you check https://github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s ?

Comment: I haven't check the github link, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can, but you shouldn't. The AWS VPC CNI is limited to the network interfaces of an EC2 instance, which means you can not have more pods than network interfaces! This is a huge cost driver and therefore better look for another CNI from the start.